# Sylow theorem and icosahedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I think this might be a stupid question.

The icosahedral group $A_5$ with order $60$ is a simple group $60=2^2\times 3\times5$
but according to Sylow theorem $A_5$ must have subgroups of order $4$.
But that's contradictory to that $A_5$ is a simple group right ?

Is $A_5$ simple?

Comment: Why do the presence of subgroups of order 4 contradict simplicity?

Comment: I believe the icosahedral group is isomorphic to $A_5$ that is simple.

Comment: I observe 3 cathegories within all non normal subgroups of icosahedral group A_5. That is also why they cannot be bound by (only) one "p-cathegory".Pecik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be recalling the definition of a simple group incorrectly. A simple group is a group $G$ whose only *normal* subgroups are the trivial group and $G$ itself. None of the order $4$ subgroups of the icosahedral group (or any of the nontrivial proper subgroups, for that matter) are normal. $I$ is isomorphic to $A_5$, which is a well-known example of a simple group.

In fact, the *only* nontrivial groups with no nontrivial proper subgroups at all are $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: I think I still didn't fully understand the definition of simple group, I am kind of comparing the definition of simple group to prime number, which seems to be incorrect.
what does "normal subgroups are the trivial group and $G$ itself" means ? I explain it as has only subgroup ${1} and G$

Comment: By definition, a simple group has no nontrivial proper **normal** subgroups. A simple group $G$ can have a nontrivial proper subgroup $H$, but if $H$ is normal in $G$ then it must be that $H = 1$ or $H = G$. In other words, the only normal subgroups of a simple group $G$ are $1$ and $G$. This says nothing about the possibility of non-normal subgroups of $G$.

Comment: @zinking: If you want to draw the analogy to prime numbers, note that the only subgroups by which you can "divide" a group (form a quotient) are **normal** subgroups. So if you want to define "simple group" as "has no nontrivial 'divisors'", then the "divisors" will refer to normal subgroups, not arbitrary subgroups.

Comment: thanks , get the idea now.